# Game of Nim - showing the remaining numbers and letting a player pick their name?

Tags: c++

I need to let player one and two choose their own name, and also display the current number after each turn. I also can't seem to get the winner to display, as the program will just end abruptly once it reaches zero with no warning. A little confused as to how to get it to work.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <cstdio> 
    using namespace std; 
    //yay friends that are more c++ savvy than I am!
    int getint() { 
        char b[50]; 
        int i, val; 
        if ( fgets( b, sizeof( b ), stdin ) == 0 ) return -1; 
        if ( sscanf( b, " %n", &i ) == 0 && i > 0 && b[i] == '\0' ) return 0; 
        if ( sscanf( b, "%u %n", &val, &i ) != 1 || i <= 0 || b[i] != '\0' ) return -2; 
        return val; 
    } 
    int main(){ 
        unsigned int remain, choice; 
        int player; //just player 1 and 2
        cout << "Welcome to the game of Nim!"; //bleh, welcome messages
        cout << endl << endl; //so everything isn't all cluttered
        cout << "How it works:" << endl; //instructions? Who needs those?
        cout << "Take turns removing 1 or 2 from the original number that was selected." << endl;
        cout << "The player that brings the pile down to 0 is the winner." << endl << endl;
        cout << "Choose a number. "; 
        if ( (remain= getint( )) < 1 ) return 0; 
        for ( player= 1; ; player= 3 - player ) { 
            cout << "Your move, player " << player << "." << endl; 
            for ( ; ; ) { 
                char *op= "1 or 2"; 
                unsigned int limit= 2; 
                switch ( remain ) { 
                case 1: 
                    cout << "There's only 1 left!" << endl; 
                    choice= 1; 
                    break; 
                case 2: 
                    op= "1 or 2", limit= 2; 
                default: 
                    cout << "How many sticks will you take (" << op << ")? "; 
                    switch ( choice= getint() ) { 
                    case -1: 
                        return 0; 
                    case -2: 
                        printf( "Syntax error in given number.\n" ); 
                    case 0: 
                        continue; 
                    default: 
                        break; 
                    } 
                    if ( choice < 1 || choice > limit ) { 
                        cout << "You can only choose " << op << "." << endl; 
                        continue; 
                    } 
                    break; 
                } 
                break; 
            } 
            remain -= choice; 
            if ( remain < 1 ) break; 
        } 
        cout << "Player " << player << " wins!" << endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name can be user inputted through `cin`, looks like you aready know how to do that, then stored to a `string[]`, where the index is for the `player-1` value.

```
string names[2];
cout << "Player 1 choose name: "; cin >> names[0];
cout << "Player 1 choose name: "; cin >> names[1];
```

Also, you're checking if an `unsigned int` is negative. That should be a compiler error.

Your `case 2` doesn't seem to change anything.

The end game outputs with these changes.